# Remove HTML tags and parse JSON array into key/value object

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, parsing

I'm working with a JSON array payload where I want to extract it into a separate object for processing downstream.

The payload is dynamic and can have multiple nested levels in the JSON array, but the first level will always have an `id` field which is the unique identifier.

```
[{'field1': [],
  'field2': {'field2_1': string,
   'field2_2': 'string',
   'field2_3': 'string'},
  'field3': '<html> strings <html>'},
  'id':1}
{'field1': [],
  'field2': {'field2_1': string,
   'field2_2': 'string',
   'field2_3': 'string'},
  'field3': '<html> strings <html>'},
  'id':2}
{'field1': [],
  'field2': {'field2_1': string,
   'field2_2': 'string',
   'field2_3': 'string'},
  'field3': '<html> strings <html>'},
  'id':3},
{'field1': [],
  'field2': {'field2_1': string,
   'field2_2': 'string',
   'field2_3': 'string'},
  'field3': '<html> strings <html>'},
  'id':4}]
```

The payload is not limited to this structure in terms of more fields or more nested fields with a different type of data. But the `id` field will always be attached to each of the objects in the payload. I want to create a dictionary(open to other suggestions for the data type) with the `id` field and everything else in that object as a cleaned-up string, without any of the brackets or HTML tags, etc.

The output should be(depending on data type) something like this:

```
{1: string string string strings,
2: string string string strings,
3: string string string strings,
4: string string string strings}
```

This is a very generic example. I'm having trouble navigating the JSON array with all the nesting and content and would just like to extract the `id` and the rest of the content in a clean manner. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `beautifulsoup` to clean the string form all tags. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


lst = [{'field1': [],
  'field2': {'field2_1': 'string1',
   'field2_2': 'string2',
   'field2_3': 'string3'},
  'field3': '<html> strings4 <html>',
  'id':1},
{'field1': [],
  'field2': {'field2_1': 'string1',
   'field2_2': 'string2',
   'field2_3': 'string3'},
  'field3': '<html> strings4 <html>',
  'id':2},
{'field1': [],
  'field2': {'field2_1': 'string1',
   'field2_2': 'string2',
   'field2_3': 'string3'},
  'field3': '<html> strings4 <html>',
  'id':3},
{'field1': [],
  'field2': {'field2_1': 'string1',
   'field2_2': 'string2',
   'field2_3': 'string3'},
  'field3': '<html> strings4 <html>',
  'id':4}]

def flatten(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for v in d.values():
            yield from flatten(v)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for v in d:
            yield from flatten(v)
    elif isinstance(d, str):
        yield d

out = {}
for d in lst:
    out[d['id']] = ' '.join(map(str.strip, BeautifulSoup(' '.join(flatten(d)), 'html.parser').find_all(text=True)))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{1: 'string1 string2 string3 strings4', 2: 'string1 string2 string3 strings4', 3: 'string1 string2 string3 strings4', 4: 'string1 string2 string3 strings4'}
```